# Retriving data from database in laravel

Tags: php

I have created a database and i can't able to access it. when on link on the link it is displaying a blank page. No errors. how can i view the page. with the below contents. i need to access only few columns from database.

**Content**

```
<table >
 <tr>
 <th><input type="checkbox"name="check" id="tes5" class="checkall"></th>
 <th>Company Name</th>
 <th>First Name</th>
 <th>Last Name</th>
 <th>Priority</th>
 <th>Lead Status</th>
 <th>Country</th>

 </tr>
 @foreach ($users as $user) {
 <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox"name="check" id="tes5" class="checkall"></td>
  <td>{{ $user->cname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->fname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->lname }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->priority }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->leadsta }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->country }}</td>

  </tr>
 @endforeach
</table>
```

**Controler**

```
  public function leadlist(){
$users = DB::table('leadlist')->select([
  "cname"=>$_GET["cname"],
  "fname"=>$_GET["fname"],
  "lname"=>$_GET["lname"],
  "priority"=>$_GET["priority"],
  "leadsta"=>$_GET["leadsta"],
  "country"=>$_GET["country"],

    ]);
   return view('forms.leads.list');
   }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('leadslist', 'crmcontroller@leadlist');
```

Comment: @Hemnath Are you sure you have records for the parameters you have passed

Comment: what are you trying to do? I am so confused by looking at you query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using select you can't retrive the data u should use `get()` to retrieve the data.

```
public function leadlist(){
$users = DB::table('leadlist')->get();
```

return view('forms.leads.list')->with('users',$users);
   }

so we are using `with('users',$users)` because it helps in view to retrieve data

Answer (score 2):

There are two issue with your code:

```
$users = DB::table('leadlist')->select([
  "cname"=>$_GET["cname"],
  "fname"=>$_GET["fname"],
  "lname"=>$_GET["lname"],
  "priority"=>$_GET["priority"],
  "leadsta"=>$_GET["leadsta"],
  "country"=>$_GET["country"],
]);
```

here, you are using `select()` in wrong way.

**Specifying A Select Clause**

Of course, you may not always want to select all columns from a database table. Using the select method, you can specify a custom select clause for the query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

So their is no meaning of passing that `$_GET["cname"]` in `select()`, specify only column name.

And, you have to pass the object to the view like:

```
return view('forms.leads.list',['users'=>$users]);
```

only then `users` is available on the view.

Comment: Thanks for help. But nothing happens i am getting a blank page showing nothing as previous.

Comment: as  i said only blank page i am seeing

Answer (score 0):

You have not pass $users object to view

```
  return view('forms.leads.list',['users'=>$users]);
```

Also you need to use `get()`

```
$users = DB::table('leadlist')->select([
  cname,
  fname,
  lname,
  priority,
  leadsta,
  country,

    ])->get();
```

You can read more about select here
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects

**Specifying A Select Clause**

Of course, you may not always want to select all columns from a database table. Using the select method, you can specify a custom select clause for the query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name', 'email as user_email')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for help. But nothing happens i am getting a blank page showing nothing as previous.

Comment: dd($users) and ppost result

Answer (score 0):

I think by mistake you are passing parameter.

Also you are not passing users to the view.

Please try this code in Controller:

```
public function leadlist(){
  $users = DB::table('leadlist')-> get();
  return view('forms.leads.list',compact('users'));
}
```

`compact('users')` is used to pass `$users` to view. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) is the link for more details on `compact()`

Comment: Thanks for help. But nothing happens i am getting a blank page showing nothing as previous.

Comment: try to print $users in controller using print_r($users); to check you are getting data from database

Comment: it's working fine with the **with('users',$users)** instead of copmact

Comment: the code is same as mentioned above only thing is instead if **compact** i replaced it with **with()** that's it. Thanks for your valuable time spending on my question.